# CSR: RegisterModuleInit without hardcoded JS filename?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, client-side-rendering, minimal-download-strategy

*Always looking to make CSR development [easier](http://iCSR.github.io)...*

This the typical CSR programming pattern:

#### We hardcode the filename inside the CSR file

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function () {
    function init() {
        var overrides = {Templates: {Fields: {}}};
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrides);
    }
    var csrfile = "~siteCollection/Style Library/MYHARDCODEDCSRFILENAME.js";
    csrfile=SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens(csrfile);
    RegisterModuleInit(csrfile, init);
    init();
});
```

#### Now I wonder

The script executes onload, so **it is the last script added to the DOM**

Can we get the filename from the **last** `<script>` definition ??

```
var scripts = document.querySelectorAll("[type='text/javascript']");
var csrfile = scripts[scripts.length-1].src.split('?')[0];
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function () {
    function init() {
        console.info('CSR init');
        var overrides = {Templates: {Fields: {}}};
        overrides.Templates.OnPostRender = function() {
          console.info('OnPostRender');
        };
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrides);
    }
    RegisterModuleInit(csrfile, init);
    init();
});
```

a quick test seems to work...

#### Questions:

- Office365/SharePoint Online accepts absolute URLs, so no need to use tokens,
  **Does an absolute URL have an impact on how SharePoint internals deal with the script?**
- I now chop off the `?ctag=9$$16.0.5104.1212` parameter, any issues there?
- Can [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) or other mulitthreading [hamsters](http://hamsters.io) interfere?

#### Lessons learned:

- This works for me because I have one CSR file that rule them all
- We are all sheep, blindly copy/pasting code...

  ```
  SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens(csrfile);
  ```

  Has 932.000 Google results,
  But is nothing but a wrapper function, [these **7** Google results](https://www.google.nl/search?q=%22SPClientRenderer.ReplaceUrlTokens%22&oq=%22SPClientRenderer.ReplaceUrlTokens%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.1496j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (now **8** )are not sheep,
  it is one less function call so shorter, better to read **and** faster:

  ```
  SPClientRenderer.ReplaceUrlTokens(csrfile);
  ```

jmx